# docker compose oci runtime error, executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: nginx, docker, yaml, docker-compose, fluentd

I'm following this post:

http://eric-price.net/blog/centralized-logging-docker-aws-elasticsearch

This is what my docker-compose.yml looks like :

```
version: "2"

services:

  fluentd:
    image: fluent/fluentd:latest
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
    command: start.sh
    networks:
      - lognet

  nginx:
    image: nginx-pixel
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
    networks:
      - lognet

networks:
  lognet:
    driver: bridge
```

my `start.sh` is in the same directory as the yml file. When I run `docker-compose up -d` this is what I get :

`ERROR: for fluentd  Cannot start service fluentd: oci runtime error: exec: "start.sh": executable file not found in $PATH
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

My docker-compose info:

```
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
docker-py version: 1.9.0
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command is executed inside the container- you are using a pulled fluentd container which does not have your start.sh file in it.  You can either

A.  bind mount it into the container

```
#docker-compose.yml
  fluentd:
    image: fluent/fluentd:latest
    volumes:
      - ./start.sh:/start.sh
    command: /start.sh
```

or B. build it into the image

```
# Dockerfile
FROM fluent/fluentd:latest
COPY start.sh /start.sh

#docker-compose.yml
  fluentd:
    build: .
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by adding this in my docker-compose : `volumes:- ./fluentd/etc:/fluentd/etc`
    `command: /fluentd/etc/start.sh`

Comment: From reading that blog post, that start.sh is not a good practice- you should run the gem installs in a Dockerfile so that you don't have to re-install them every time you run your container.