# Cannot start service php-fpm: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I am working in a few containers (for learn Docker) and this is what I have so far:

- A CentOS 7 [container](https://github.com/reypm/docker-centos7-supervisord)
- A Nginx [container](https://github.com/reypm/docker-nginx) inherit from previous CentOS7
- A PHP71-FPM [container](https://github.com/reypm/docker-php-fpm) inherit from previous Nginx

I am trying them from a [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker) file that looks as follow:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: "php71-fpm-nginx"
    image: reynierpm/docker-php-fpm
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 9001:9001
    environment:
        PHP_ERROR_REPORTING: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE'
        STATUS_PAGE_ALLOWED_IP: '127.0.0.1'
    volumes:
        - D:\Development\www\:/data/www
    links:
        - db
  db:
    container_name: "db_mysql"
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "gT927twQVwN2du&F!29*$Jb2"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "nortwind"
        MYSQL_USER: "user_db"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "4t6V2M3@2Q2CDpxYb*fp6e8V"
    volumes:
        - D:\Development\data\db:/var/lib/mysql
  elk:
    container_name: "elk"
    image: willdurand/elk
    ports:
        - 81:80
    volumes:
        - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
        - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns
    volumes_from:
        - php-fpm
```

As soon as I run: `docker-compose up -d` it ends with the following message:

```
> docker-compose up -d
WARNING: The Jb2 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
db_mysql is up-to-date
Starting php71-fpm-nginx

ERROR: for php-fpm  Cannot start service php-fpm: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247:
 starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/config/bootstrap.sh\\\": permission denied\"\n"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I have found some post speaking about the same issue:

- [docker compose oci runtime error, executable file not found in $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665943/docker-compose-oci-runtime-error-executable-file-not-found-in-path)
- [Oci runtime error docker-compose not a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991324/oci-runtime-error-docker-compose-not-a-directory)
- And this [search results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS718US718&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=Cannot%20start%20service%20php-fpm:%20invalid%20header%20field%20value%20%22oci%20runtime%20error:%20container_linux.go:247:%20starting%20container%20)

But nothing from there works for me. I know I am missing something but I am not able to find what is, can I get any help from community?

Comment: `exec: /config/bootstrap.sh: permission denied`, looks like some permissions issue

Comment: @the_nuts permission within the container or host permissions?

Comment: @the_nuts thanks, indeed it was a permissions issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that file `/config/bootstrap.sh` hasn't proper permissions on first parent image:

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN \
  yum update -y && \
  yum install -y epel-release && \
  yum install -y iproute python-setuptools hostname inotify-tools yum-utils which jq && \
  yum clean all && \
  easy_install supervisor
COPY container-files /
VOLUME ["/data"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/config/bootstrap.sh"]
```

Adding `RUN chmod +x /config/bootstrap.sh` make this to work properly:

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN \
  yum update -y && \
  yum install -y epel-release && \
  yum install -y iproute python-setuptools hostname inotify-tools yum-utils which jq && \
  yum clean all && \
  easy_install supervisor
COPY container-files /
RUN chmod +x /config/bootstrap.sh
VOLUME ["/data"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/config/bootstrap.sh"]
```